# Find if a file is video in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am using ruby-2.1 and I want to check if a file is of type video.
I want a solution for common for all operating systems.

So I tried the File Object. It has a fnmatch method which only tests for extensions using regex such as *.mp4 or *.avi and so on. But this seems very inefficient.

```
# Get all files of directory
all_files = Dir.entries(Dir.pwd).select { |x| !File.directory? x}

mp4_f = '*.mp4'
avi_f = '*.avi'
mkv_f = '*.mkv'
flv_f = '*.flv'

# Loop through each file
all_files.each do |file|
    puts File.fnmatch(mp4_f, file) || File.fnmatch(avi_f, file) || File.fnmatch(mkv_f, file) || File.fnmatch(flv_f, file)
end
```

But this code seems very bad for multitudes of video types.
So any solutions, would be appreciated including any gem support. Thanks.

Comment: you need read about `fffmpeg` https://www.ffmpeg.org/

Comment: Your entire example can be [refactored into two lines of code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26563825/1301972). Don't loop or compare in interpreted code when a Ruby core module can do it for you at C speeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use something like [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) and parse its output:

```
`ffmpeg -i somefile.doc`
#=> ....
#=> Invalid data found when processing input

`ffmpeg -i somefile.mp4`
#=> ...
#=> Duration: 00:00:29.84, start: 0.547944, bitrate: 390 kb/s
#=> ...
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this gem: streamio-ffmpeg, but it's showing error in ruby 2.1.

Comment: did you install ffmpeg binaries?

Answer (score 2):

### Use Globbing

One cross-platform way to do this without external dependencies like libmagic is to use [Dir#glob](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob) to match filename extensions. For example:

```
extensions  = %w[avi flv mkv mov mp4]
video_files = extensions.flat_map { |ext| Dir.glob "*#{ext}" }
```

You can then pass the *video_files* [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Array.html) around as needed within your program.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this without using the ffmpeg library,

```
vid_formats = %w[.avi .flv .mkv .mov .mp4] #add more extensions if anything is left
all_files.each do |file|
   puts vid_formats.include? File.extname(file)
end
```

Of course you have to maintain an array for the extension but this looks better in terms of code readability. Hope that helps

Comment: This is hugely inefficient. Why would you compare the files one-by-one in a loop like this, when you can collect them all at C speed?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @CodeGnome. Here, a very specific problem is solved, which is getting rid of two many `if` conditions.